# flvFPW1() - What does it do?

Tags: javascript

I've been tasked with rewriting the Javascript engine currently powering my customer's internal website. While reviewing the code I've come across this function *flvFPW1* which I do not recognize, nor can I decipher the code(my Javascript knowledge is modest at best). A Google search gives me a few hits, but most if not all page hits are from the Javascript used on that particular page. In other words, I cannot find a description for this function, even though it is obviously used by others.

Can someone here enlighten me?

Thanks / Fredrik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My own research agrees that it's a dreamweaver extension:  I found [code for version 1.44](http://forums.devshed.com/javascript-development-115/apply-onclick-to-all-links-in-template-265457.html) (scroll down some on this page) rather than 1.3:

```
function flvFPW1(){//v1.44
var v1=arguments,v2=v1[2].split(","),v3=(v1.length>3)?v1[3]:false,v4=(v1.length>4)?parseInt(v1[4]):0,
v5=(v1.length>5)?parseInt(v1[5]):0,v6,v7=0,v8,v9,v10,v11,v12,v13,v14,v15,v16;v11=
new Array("width,left,"+v4,"height,top,"+v5);for (i=0;i<v11.length;i++){v12=v11[i].split(",");l_iTarget=parseInt(v12[2]);
if (l_iTarget>1||v1[2].indexOf("%")>-1){v13=eval("screen."+v12[0]);
for (v6=0;v6<v2.length;v6++){v10=v2[v6].split("=");
if (v10[0]==v12[0]){v14=parseInt(v10[1]);if (v10[1].indexOf("%")>-1){v14=(v14/100)*v13;v2[v6]=v12[0]+"="+v14;}}
if (v10[0]==v12[1]){v16=parseInt(v10[1]);v15=v6;}}
if (l_iTarget==2){v7=(v13-v14)/2;v15=v2.length;}
else if (l_iTarget==3){v7=v13-v14-v16;}v2[v15]=v12[1]+"="+v7;}}v8=v2.join(",");v9=window.open(v1[0],v1[1],v8);
if (v3){v9.focus();}document.MM_returnValue=false;return v9;}
```

Which was, of course, passed through a compressor to save bandwidth making it very hard to read.  I spent a little bit of time un-obfuscating it before I realized that I could get better results by adding "dreamweaver" to my search string.  Doing that I was able to find some more interesting documentation:

http://www.flevooware.nl/dreamweaver/extdetails.asp?extID=8  (short description)
  http://satsuki.altervista.org/basibloggers/source40.txt (full script code, in italian)

In short: it's basically just a wrapper for `window.open`.  Here's the progress I made translating the code:

```
function flvFPW1()
{//v1.44
    var v1=arguments;  // pass v1[0] and v1[1] directly to window.open
    var arg3=v1[2].split(",");
    var focusNewWindow=(v1.length>3)?v1[3]:false;
    var newWindowWidth=(v1.length>4)?parseInt(v1[4]):0;
    var newWindowHeight=(v1.length>5)?parseInt(v1[5]):0;

    var adjustedWindowPosition=0,result,keyValuePair,AxisProperty;
    var windowSize,sizeValue,arg3Index,anchorValue;

    var hwArray= new Array("width,left,"+newWindowWidth,"height,top,"+newWindowHeight);
    for (i=0;i<hwArray.length;i++)  // x-axis, then y-axis
    {
        AxisProperty=hwArray[i].split(","); // {"width", "left", 0}  or {"height", "top", 0}
        l_iTarget=parseInt(AxisProperty[2]);  // l_iTarget defined where?

        if (l_iTarget>1||v1[2].indexOf("%")>-1)  
        {
            screenSize=eval("screen."+AxisProperty[0]); // x or y size of the window
            for (var i=0;i<arg3.length;i++)
            {
                keyValuePair=arg3[i].split("=");
                if (keyValuePair[0]==AxisProperty[0]) // if the key is (width|height)
                {
                    sizeValue=parseInt(keyValuePair[1]);
                    if (keyValuePair[1].indexOf("%")>-1)
                    {
                        sizeValue=(sizeValue/100)* screenSize;
                        arg3[i]=AxisProperty[0]+"="+sizeValue;
                    }
                }

                if (keyValuePair[0]==AxisProperty[1])  // if the key is (left|top)
                {
                    anchorValue=parseInt(keyValuePair[1]);
                    arg3Index=i;
                }
            }
            if (l_iTarget==2)
            {
                adjustedWindowPosition=(screenSize-sizeValue)/2; // will center the window on this axix
                arg3Index=arg3.length;
            }
            else if (l_iTarget==3)
            {
                adjustedWindowPosition= screenSize-sizeValue-anchorValue;
            }
            arg3[arg3Index]=AxisProperty[1]+"="+adjustedWindowPosition;  // (left|top) = value
        }
    }
    var newArg3=arg3.join(",");
    result=window.open(v1[0],v1[1],newArg3);
    if (focusNewWindow)
    {
        result.focus();
    }

    document.MM_returnValue=false;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: That much didn't take long:  what I've been doing is also giving the variables meaningful names and adding comments.

Answer (score 1):

on your site, type in this in the location bar:

```
javascript:alert(flvFPW1);
```

it will report the function code

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a built in function, so it is just some function one of your team wrote.

It might be a function that Dreamweaver adds to a page to do something though...

Answer (score 0):

Install Firefox (http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/) and the FireBug extension(https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843).  Use FireBug's DOM tab to find the function and click on it in the right column.  It will take you to the file/line that the function is defined on.

Or open the HTML page in your favorite powerful text editor (like TextPad or TextMate) and do a Search/Find for the function name.

If you're saying that you've found the function but can't actually understand it, then you should probably paste the code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Google yields:

```
function flvFPW1() { // v1.3
    // Copyright 2002, Marja Ribbers-de Vroed, FlevOOware (www.flevooware.nl/dreamweaver/)
    var v1 = arguments, v2 = v1[2].split(","), v3 = (v1.length > 3) ? v1[3] : false, v4 = (v1.length > 4) ? parseInt(v1[4]) : 0, v5 = (v1.length > 5) ? parseInt(v1[5]) : 0, v6, v7 = 0, v8, v9, v10, v11, v12, v13, v14, v15, v16, v17, v18;
    if (v4 > 1) {
        v10 = screen.width;
        for (v6 = 0; v6 < v2.length; v6++) {
            v18 = v2[v6].split("=");
            if (v18[0] == "width") {
                v8 = parseInt(v18[1]);
            }
            if (v18[0] == "left") {
                v9 = parseInt(v18[1]);
                v11 = v6;
            }
        }
        if (v4 == 2) {
            v7 = (v10 - v8) / 2;
            v11 = v2.length;
        } else if (v4 == 3) {
            v7 = v10 - v8 - v9;
        }
        v2[v11] = "left=" + v7;
    }
    if (v5 > 1) {
        v14 = screen.height;
        for (v6 = 0; v6 < v2.length; v6++) {
            v18 = v2[v6].split("=");
            if (v18[0] == "height") {
                v12 = parseInt(v18[1]);
            }
            if (v18[0] == "top") {
                v13 = parseInt(v18[1]);
                v15 = v6;
            }
        }
        if (v5 == 2) {
            v7 = (v14 - v12) / 2;
            v15 = v2.length;
        } else if (v5 == 3) {
            v7 = v14 - v12 - v13;
        }
        v2[v15] = "top=" + v7;
    }
    v16 = v2.join(",");
    v17 = window.open(v1[0], v1[1], v16);
    if (v3) {
        v17.focus();
    }
    document.MM_returnValue = false;
}
```

The URL in the comment leads to:

[FlevOOware - Dreamweaver Extensions - Popup Link](http://www.flevooware.nl/dreamweaver/extdetails.asp?extID=8)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping out guys! spilth: Yes I found the function in the js-file but couldn't comprehend the code. Since I found the same function on several other pages that were not related to my customer's page I assumed its purpose would already be known by other people.. so I didn't bother with posting the code. I will next time though.

Best Regards